# How do I model a 'Central Library' in TFS 2010?

Tags: git, tfs

I'm currently evaluating TFS 2010 for use in our development team as the source control solution instead of Git. We're a Microsoft shop, dipping our fingers into Sharepoint and Project Server anyway so it would be nice to have it all running in one platform.

My problem starts with this...

In Git, we have a development model that sees our Company's OWN re-usable code-base stored in a separate repository. Each client solution also has its own repository and a sub-module (extern for SVN-junkies) linking it to our common library. In order to allow for developers to add functionality to our common library as they go, we set up a tracked branch for each sub-module and merge the bits of functionality into our common-library as they are finalised.

So (in a kickback to old ascii art) a rough representation of our Git set up would be...

```
    Common-Library::(branch) -----> (submodule)::Client-Solution
                        ^                |
                        |-----------------
```

This structure is very important to our effectiveness. It allows developers to update our common libraries in context, in solution, at the same time as they develop their client solutions.  More importantly, it allows newly developed functionality to find its way back into our common library in a requirements driven, organic manner by merging from the client branch back into the master and into other client solutions.

My problem is that I really want to use TFS 2010 for all the other workflow good stuff, but I'm having a hard time getting my head around how such a model could fit into its Source Control capability. It seems pretty stand-alone. So far, I can't find anything describing how to set up external references such as 'submodule'.

- Does TFS 2010 have such a capability?
- Perhaps my understanding of TFS 2010's model is falling short?
- How would you set up a shared common library model in TFS 2010?

Comment: You are making a big mistake moving from Git to TFS. I would highly recommend not doing so.

Comment: but if he wants to use other features of TFS (workitems, reports, builds...) its comprehensible that he wants to move

Comment: I'm a massive fan of Git, and I would give a lot to be able to use it instead of TFS's integrated source control. However, in terms of workflow TFS's workflow features are compelling. We're faced with the option of adapting to with TFS's source model and using its workflow features vs keeping Git and spending a fair bit of time and effort to integrate other third party tools with Project Server etc. If you have any other suggestions, I'm more than open to them.

Comment: I really hope you stuck with git and are now using the git integrated TFS.

Comment: @Stephen yeah actually I dumped this whole idea and I've been a git aficionado ever since. Haven't looked back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can map this in your local workspaces if you have say:

```
$/.../Projects/YourProject
```

and

```
$/.../Libs/LibA
```

You can set your local workspace to

```
Status  Source Control Folder        Local Folder
Active  $/.../Projects/YourProject   C:\..\YourProject
Active  $/.../Libs/LibA              C:\..\YourProject\Libs
```

So your libraries can exist anywhere in your TFS project, but locally they will be available in a reasonable location for you to add to your solution.  Any changes you make can then be saved correctly in the respository, and anyone else working using those shared projects will see it locally in their workspace when it's updated.

Update:

If you want to use branched version, say you have

```
$/.../Customer1/Libs/LibA
```

and

```
$/.../Customer2/Libs/LibA
```

Both are branched off

```
$/.../Libs/LibA
```

If you're doing work for Customer1, then you change your mapping from

```
Active  $/.../Libs/LibA              C:\..\YourProject\Libs
```

to

```
Active  $/.../Customer1/Libs/LibA    C:\..\YourProject\Libs
```

Everything should still be in the same place as the Local Folder hasn't changed.

(tbh, this isn't an brilliant example, but I hope it makes it a bit clearer or gives you some ideas!)

Comment: This is a good start. You can achieve roughly the same thing in or out of source control by keeping your library in a centrally mapped drive etc.

The missing component for me is to be able to create a client-specific branch of LibA, so that changes to the common library made during development on YourProject do not impact other clients until we choose to merge changes deliberately.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What if your local workspace mapping for LibA pointed to a branch of LibA?

Comment: Yes that's totally fine, you can change your local workspace at any time, so you just delete the mapping to the `LibA` and map it to the branched version.  I'll edit my original post to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Is such a structure a way for you to go?

[image]

Now you can start your `Client 1` and branch the mainline of `Common Lib A` to `Client 1/devline/Common Lib A`

If you made changes in the `Common Lib A` and are finished you can merge the branch in Client 1 with the mainline or possible better an integration line.

An other solution is to use the common lib in client applications as assemblies which I prefer.

If I come in the situation that something is missing in the Common lib I create a new requirement/backlog item for the common lib (it has an extra area path) and implement it in the branch of the `Common Lib A`, test it and deploy it to my application(s).

You can take a look at [the branching guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) if not already done, perhaps you get more ideas.

**Edit based on comment**

When you branch you can specify the folder via `browse`.
There you select your target branch.
[image]

After done that, you can add the sources of `Common Lib A` in you client solutions.

Comment: This sounds like its closer to what I'm looking for. The big advantage to the model we have in Git, is that each client solution has its own clone of Common Lib A which is a branched from the Common Lib A's 'mainline'.  So, for example, you'd have branches Common-ClientA, Common-ClientB etc and each ClientA would add .vsproj from Common-ClientA.  It allows developers to work on the common libraries from the same solution as the client solution. They never have to specifically make changes to Common Lib A. Could a folder underneath Client 1 be mapped to a branch of Common Lib A?