# How to reference code in website

Tags: asp.net, tfs

My code is divided into websites, one for each module (in TFS). Also, I have some application level code (like loginpage.aspx, webconfig.xml, Configuration.xml, Common.css, Logo.gif, masterpage.js, mainmaster.master, mainmaster.master.cs,  etc) which is common for all module level websites. Is there a way I can reference the common application level files in each module level website. I want to avoid multiple copies of the application level code, by using a reference or some other mechanism.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757186/how-do-i-model-a-central-library-in-tfs-2010

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this kind of shared code is in your solution-structure, so TFS can stay straightforward and your common code is not duplicated localy either.

So try to make the common-code shared by creating a project that provide baseclasses where the other projcets (the websites) can build on.